# Rosbridge - isConnected()?

Tags: ros, rosbridge, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working with Rosbridge at the moment, and trying to determine from the ROS side (server) whether the websocket connection is ok. Is there a isConnected() or ping() type function that will enable me to determine the connection status? I need a test that determines the current connection reliability for use with wireless/3G/4G connected ROS devices, which will frequently drop messages without disconnecting from the socket. (They stay 'sort of' connected).

I'm trying to do something like:

if (isConnected())
{
- Send messages from subscribed topics -
}
else
{
- Save the messages, instead -
}

I tried using a service, but it seems I'm using rosbridge a little bit backwards; since a service initiated from the web-side wouldn't help.

'My apologies in advance for being completely wrong about everything ever.'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107121/rosbridge---isconnected()-?/) by [Chengarda](https://answers.ros.org/users/9541/chengarda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having found no reasonable alternative, I've gone with a combination of a service and a topic to achieve this. The devices post the number of stored messages on a topic, and the web server calls a data-fetching service this number of times. It's working, but seems very heavy handed for such a simple problem.

---

Originally posted by [Chengarda](https://answers.ros.org/users/9541/chengarda/) with karma: 156 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0